# Function each() has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0

Tags: php, function, foreach, each

How can I update my code to avoid using function each()?

```
if (count($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
       while (list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
       print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$val\">\n";
      }
}
```

I tried with this solution but no go:

```
if (count($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
           foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $val) {
           print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$val\">\n";
          }
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong using just $_POST ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_POST`

```
if (count($_POST)) {
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$val\">\n";
  }
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php for more info

Comment: Thank you, this is ok now. I have similar code somewhere else, but how should I solve this one? `if (count($_SESSION)) { while (list($key, $val) = each($_SESSION)) { $$key = $val; } }` I got this warning: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/igor/public_html/foto/const.inc.php

Comment: @Igor its because your $_SESSION is empty or a string, that can't be counted. You should validate the $_SESSION with is_array() before count()

Answer (score -1):

`list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)`

change to

```
function a_each(&$arr){
    $key = key($arr);
    if (!$key)
        return false;
    $val = current($arr);
    next($arr);
    return array($key, $val);
}

list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS);
```

Comment: It either [raises an error](https://3v4l.org/SH4UW) or [causes an infinite loop if used as `each` is supposed to be used](https://3v4l.org/SacGW).